# Graphs the same size in gnuplot multiplot when each take up most of its canvas and one has labels

Tags: loops, gnuplot, margin, spacing

I've reedited this question a few times: I've made some good progress!

So, as I understand it, multiplot splits the whole canvas up into equal sized parts as needed. This is a little weird when your different plots have different dimensions, as in my case, but it works. The problem might come in when the graph are supposed to be very close together (e.g. each takes up most of its canvas), but one of them has labels. In that case, it seems the plot with labels must resize to be smaller so everything can fit. That's where I am now.

I see a few options.

1. make all the plots farther apart-- but I don't want to do that.
2. somehow make the label not part of the multiplot-- I would totally do this, but I don't know how. It's possible even just the axis tics themselves would be too big, but I can probably deal with that or compromise just that amount on the spacing.

So my question is, how can I put words in a gnuplot graph, completely separately from a plot?

(The picture is also giant, which is unfortunate, it was the only way I could make the formatting work)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Multiplot has a convenience mode `layout <rows>, <columns>` that, as you say, splits the page into equal rectangles.  But you do not have to use this convenience mode; you can assign each sub-plot to any arbitrary rectangle on the page, even one that overlaps or is interior to another rectangle.  Here is an example from the online demo set that is close to what you show:
   [Demo of multiple plots with explicit alignment of borders](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/margins.html)
   [image]
2. Placing text anywhere on the page: The `set label` command allows you to position the text using screen coordinates rather than plot coordinates. For example, to place a single large label centered at the top  of a page that contains multiple plots:

```
    set label 1 "This label is positioned independent of all plots"
    set label 1 at screen 0.5, screen 0.95 center
    set label 1 font "Times,20"
```

Comment: Thanks! I definitely should have included more code- I think I will try to offset the multiplot from the left edge and do your #2, because actually what I am doing is "set multiplot 3,5" then a "do for" loops for each row, iterating through numbers that aren't equally spaced. I don't know how to set l/rmargin differently for each one; I haven't found a way to increment a counter in a loop in gnuplot. Since it's 15 plots I really don't want to give up the convenience of the do for loop.

Comment: updating-- the functionality I was looking for was totally word()! I wanted to make "lists" and call "indeces" of them. Now my loops are just like "do for i=[1:5]"- even though my parameters aren't evenly spaced- and I can use i in the calculation for lmargin, AND as an index! You were right! No convenience mode is much better.